# Is it possible to import css file conditionally in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have my admin-panel and pages for clients in one `Vue.js project`. Is it possible to use certain `css-files` only if the current route has `"forAdmin"` meta?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: @DecadeMoon yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `style-loader` with the [useable](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#useable) API, you can dynamically apply and remove a stylesheet in your code.

First you'll need to update your webpack config rules so that stylesheets with the `.useable.css` extension will be loaded with the *useable* API:

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /\.useable.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader'
  ]
},
{
  test: /\.useable\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader/useable',
    'css-loader'
  ]
}
```

Now in your router code file, you can import your stylesheet and `.use()` and `.unuse()` it according to your condition:

```js
import style from './admin.useable.css'

const router = new VueRouter(...)

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  for (const route of to.matched) {
    if (route.meta.forAdmin) {
      style.use()
    }
  }

  for (const route of from.matched) {
    if (route.meta.forAdmin) {
      style.unuse()
    }
  }
})
```

Make sure you balance the total number of `.use()` and `.unuse()` calls correctly because a reference count is maintained behind the scenes to figure out when the stylesheet should be applied.

I'm not sure what your setup is, so there might be a better way of doing what you want though.

Comment: if I would do that in webpack config. Does it works when it is in production? thanks thanks :) I like the idea here, but is this a good way, interchanging themes? thanks thanks

Comment: I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work in production, provided that the production CSS loaders are the same as for development. It won't work if you are doing something different in production, like extracting the CSS to a file.

Answer (score 6):

In your `mounted()` function you can add it like this.

```
if(someCondition) {
    var element = document.createElement("link");
    element.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    element.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    element.setAttribute("href", "external.css");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking something like you answered. Thanks

Comment: How about SCSS files? they need to be compiled